# Получить папку выбранного файла

Tags: android

Работаю с браузером, хочу добавить поддержку выбора файла из андроид устройства, для этого запуская примерно такой интент

```
    val cameraIntents: MutableList<Intent> = ArrayList()
    val captureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    val packageManager = activity.packageManager
    val listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0)
    for (res in listCam) {
        val packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName
        val intent = Intent(captureIntent)
        intent.component = ComponentName(packageName, res.activityInfo.name)
        intent.setPackage(packageName)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(File("")))
        cameraIntents.add(intent)
    }

    // Filesystem.
    val galleryIntent = Intent()
    galleryIntent.type = getMime(prompt = prompt)
    galleryIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
        galleryIntent,
        appContext.getString(R.string.select_source)
    )

    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toTypedArray())

    if (prompt.type == FilePrompt.Type.MULTIPLE) {
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    }
    if (!prompt.mimeTypes.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, prompt.mimeTypes)
    }

    activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, filePickerRequestCode)
```

В ActivityResult получаю Uri такого вида `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A14490`

как из этого получить  file:///blablabal (поесть реальную папку)

Comment: [Несколько ответов](https://coderoad.ru/20067508/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-URI-Android-KitKat-new-storage-access-framework)

Comment: Ну да, поиском тоже это находил, и использую первый вариант. Но безопасно ли  использовать код в котором захардкожены расположения папок, не будет ли проблем в кастомных андроид сборках самсунга, гуаве и прочих (которые любят что то поменять в андроиде)